# esp8266 ch_pd pulled 3v3 - red led comes down

Tags: connection, esp8266, led

I have a problem with connecting my esp8266 01 wifi module.
GPIO0 connected to GND.
RESET pulled to 3.3v.
When I pull ch_pd pin to 3.3v, the red led comes down. I also tried put a resistor (220 and 10k) between 3.3v and ch_pd pin, but it didnt help.

I have to newer version of esp8266 01, the black one.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com would be a more appropriate place to ask this.

Comment: Great site, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I made it! The problem was that my first power source has **3.31V and 4,5A**, then I used arduino uno as a power source, which has these parameters **3.18V and 370mA** and ch_pd could be pulled to power source and red still flash.

In the first case I used resistor divider from 5V to 3.3V with 3x 1kOhm resitors.
In the second case(arduino uno) no resistor or capacitor was needed.

This problem was probably caused be too big current on ch_pd pin.